# Unexpected page handling (also, VirtualLock = no op?)

Tags: windows, virtual-memory

This morning I stumbled across a surprising number of page faults where I did not expect them. Yes, I probably should not worry, but it still strikes me odd, because in my understanding they should not happen. And, I'd like better if they didn't.

The application (under WinXP Pro 32bit) reserves a larger section (1GB) of address space with `VirtualAlloc(MEM_RESERVE)` and later allocates moderately large blocks (20-50MB) of memory with `VirtualAlloc(MEM_COMMIT)`. This is done in a worker ahead of time, the intent being to stall the main thread as little as possible. Obviously, you cannot ever assure that no page faults happen unless the memory region is currently locked, but a few of them are certainly tolerable (and unavoidable). Surprisingly *every single page* faults. Always.

The assumption was thus that the system only creates pages lazily after allocating them, which somehow makes sense too (although the documentation suggests something different). Fair enough, my bad.
The obvious workaround is therefore `VirtualLock`/`VirtualUnlock`, which forces the system to create those pages, as they *must* exist after `VirtualLock` returns. Surprisingly, *still every single page faults*.

So I wrote a little test program which did all above steps in sequence, sleeping 5 seconds in between each, to rule out something was wrong in the other code. The results were:

- `MEM_RESERVE` 1GB ---> success, zero CPU, zero time, nothing happens
- `MEM_COMMIT` 1 GB ---> success, zero CPU, zero time, working set increases by 2MB, 512 page faults (respectively 8 bytes of metadata allocated in user space per page)
- `for(... += 128kB) { VirtualLock(128kB); VirtualUnlock(128kB); }` ---> success, zero CPU, zero time, nothing happens
- `for(... += 4096) *addr = 0;` ---> 262144 page faults, about 0.25 seconds (~95% kernel time). 1GB increase for both "working set" and "physical" inside Process Explorer
- `VirtualFree` ---> zero CPU, zero time, both "working set" and "physical" instantly go * poof *.

My expectation was that since each page had been locked once, it must physically exist *at least after that*. It might of course still be moved in and out of the WS as the quota is exceeded (merely changing one reference as long as sufficient RAM is available). Yet, neither the execution time, nor the working set, nor the physical memory metrics seem to support this. Rather, as it looks, each single accessed page is created upon faulting, even if it had been locked previously. Of course I *can* touch every page manually in a worker thread, but there must be a cleaner way too?

Am I making a wrong assumption about what `VirtualLock` *should* do or am I not understanding something right about virtual memory? Any idea about how to tell the OS in a "clean, legitimate, working" way that I'll be wanting memory, and I'll be wanting it *for real*?

**UPDATE:**
In reaction to Harry Johnston's suggestion, I tried the somewhat problematic approach of actually calling `VirtualLock` on a gigabyte of memory. For this to succeed, you must first set the process' working set size accordingly, since the default quotas are 200k/1M, which means `VirtualLock` cannot possibly lock a region larger than 200k (or rather, it cannot lock more than 200k *alltogether*, and that is minus what is already locked for I/O or for another reason).

After setting a minimum working set size of 1GB and a maximum of 2GB, all the page faults happen the moment `VirtualAlloc(MEM_COMMIT)` is called. "Virtual size" in Process Explorer jumps up by 1GB instantly. So far, it looked really, really good.
However, looking closer, "Physical" remains as it is, actual memory is really only used the moment you touch it.

`VirtualLock` remains a no-op (fault-wise), but raising the minimum working set size *kind of* got closer to the goal.

There are two problems with tampering the WS size, however. First, you're generally not meant to have a gigabyte of minimum working set in a process, because the OS tries hard to keep that amount of memory locked. This would be acceptable in my case (it's actually more or less just what I ask for).
The bigger problem is that `SetProcessWorkingSetSize` needs the the `PROCESS_SET_QUOTA` access right, which is no problem as "administrator", but it fails when you run the program as a restricted user (for a good reason), and it triggers the "allow possibly harmful program?" alert of some well-known Russian antivirus software (for *no* good reason, but alas, you can't turn it off).

Comment: What happens if you don't call VirtualUnlock in the first loop?  Arguably, VirtualLock + VirtualUnlock together are a noop, so perhaps the compiler is optimizing them out of existence.

Comment: @Harry Johnston: Keeping a gigabyte of memory locked is problematic, but nevertheless interesting, see the update to the question (to follow in a minute).

Comment: What's happening is that each `VirtualLock` is re-using the memory unlocked by the previous `VirtualUnlock`, so you merely cycled all your app's memory through a 128kb window. Assuming you don't have quota privilege or "lock physical pages" privilege, you could have the main thread signal the worker thread "I'm currently using memory X, and I'm going to be needing X+1 soon" and then the worker thread can go unlock X-1 and lock X+1, trying to stay one step ahead of the main thread.

Comment: @RaymondChen: That would be a kind of "prefetching on page level", which would probably work with a more or less linear, predicatable access pattern. Though I guess that it's probably less trouble if I indeed stay with just touching every page once. My concern is not so much about locking pages in RAM before they are accessed (the target machines have enough physical RAM so it's a rather safe bet that a gigabyte worth of pages stays in RAM), but about actually _creating_ the pages upon allocation, so this needs not happen later. Locking does not seem to do that, if Proc Explorer isn't lying.

Comment: @RaymondChen: Since you already gave the good answer about cycling through the same 128k all over (it's not what I hoped for, I'd like it to work... but it's definitively _what happens_), if you were so kind to convert your comment to a question, I'd accept that one.

Comment: @Damon Go ahead and post the answer yourself and accept it. (It's not clear how you could have expected anything else. If you free memory and then allocate memory, you're probably going to get the same memory back that you just freed. Same thing going on with quota.)

Comment: When I allocate and free memory, I am telling someone (the CRT or the OS) that I am no longer interested in that memory. It's therefore logical, and due to cache even desirable, to reuse it. When I lock/unlock a range, I'm telling the OS that I absolutely need it to be present in physical RAM, and then I don't _absolutely_ need that constraint any more. However, I'm still possibly using it. Given 7GiB of unused physical RAM available, my expectation was that the most valid assumption an OS could make is it's best to use a different block of physical memory for the next request...

Comment: ... very much similar to how the file cache works, too. If you unmap a file mapping, it is not automatically "gone" from RAM either. I've done this many times before, mapping a file that was previously (minutes ago!) mapped instantly pops it back into existence as if it was never gone, even hundreds of megabytes in size. Only if you push the OS hard so it has no other choice, it starts throwing away stuff. Insofar, I found that your comment that it just cycles through the same 128k again and again was surprising. But, it perfectly explains what I'm seeing.

Comment: You never accessed the memory before the lock or during the lock period. Therefore, at no time was memory ever assigned to the address. The first access takes place after all the lock/unlock games are over, at which point it is a standard first access (assign physical memory on first access).

Comment: The kernel does a read-access of the memory during NtLockVirtualMemory which will trigger the first access behaviour.

Comment: Actually my bad. There's an read during the NtLockVirtualMemory, but not a readPF because the NtAllocateVirtualMemory backs the page with the MM's zero-page with a CopyOnWrite so there's no PF on the read. What you're seeing is the fact that there hasn't been a *write* PF on the page before or since, so your first write to the page occurs after the lock causing a PF that triggers a CopyOnWrite -> PAGE_READWRITE conversion, which is independent of the VirtualLock/Unlock that happened earlier, hence you see a page fault on every access after the VirtualLock/Unlock.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically VirtualLock is a hint, and so the OS is allowed to ignore it. It's backed by the NtLockVirtualMemory syscall which on Reactos/Wine is implemented as a no-op, however Windows does back the syscall with real work (MiLockVadRange).

VirtualLock isn't guarranteed to succeed. Calls to this function require the SE_LOCK_MEMORY_PRIVILEGE to work, and the addresses must fulfil security and quota restrictions. Additionally after a VirtualUnlock, the kernel is no longer obliged to keep your page in memory, so a page fault after that is a valid action.

And as Raymond Chen points out, when you unlock the memory it can formally release the page. This means that the next VirtualLock on the next page might obtain that very same page again, so when you touch the original page you'll still get a page-fault.

Comment: Sorry, I have to disagree on your answer. According to the documentation, VirtualLock is very clearly not a hint, locking pages is not understood that way under other systems (e.g. the POSIX equivalent `mlock`) either. Whether or not the function is broken in ReactOS is not irrelevant. It is true that VirtualLock is not guaranteed to succeed, but again this is irrelevant, since the question states that it _does_ succeed, yet the result is not what's expected. It is true that the kernel is not obliged to keep a page that is not locked in memory, but this is a sophistry...

Comment: ... the question is not about _some_ pages faulting (I am very well aware that page faults may happen and _will_ happen), but about _all_ pages faulting every single time, no exception. The decisively important thing is what Raymond Chen basically pointed out is that the OS is kind of "cheating" by only ever showing the same few pages to you (or anyone else), as long as nobody actually touches them, without even creating pages that it guarantees formally exist at a given time (after being locked).

Comment: When I said "hint" I meant you are asking the kernel to do something that the kernel can choose to not do. Actually the very same Raymond Chen noted here (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/11/06/5924058.aspx) that locking pages into memory DOESNT guarantee that the pages get paged out, and hence DOESNT guarantee that subsequent touches don't incur a page-fault. Reactos and Wine implement it as a NOP because the cost of implementing this function is high given the fact that it is a hint.

Comment: The reason why *all* of your pages are causing a page-fault later is because they are all still in their initial condition of being zero - which means that they are all backed by the kernel zero page and marked by the kernel as copy-on-write. Consequently when you touch the pages for writing in your example, each touch on each page causes a page fault whilst the kernel allocates a new page, copies the old page and then returns execution to you. VirtualLock locks your memory into the working set of the process ...

Comment: ... there's no guarrantee that all of those pages are backed by physical memory at the same actual (PAE) protection as the Windows lpProtect-ion of the pages, and hence even if you VirtualLock the entire region properly, you'll still get a page-fault on each page as you touch it for the first time.

Comment: The kernel _cannot_ choose. The documentation (which unlike ReactOS is authorative) says: _"Locks the specified [...] into physical memory, ensuring that subsequent access to the region will not incur a page fault. [...] Pages [...] remain in physical memory until the process unlocks them or terminates. These pages are guaranteed not to be written to the pagefile [...]"_. To the letter of the wording, this means the OS must provide pages that exist in phyiscal RAM, no room for interpretation, or any "if" or "when". In the article you liked, note the last paragraph ("follow-up").

Comment: I concede that I didn't check page protections, though... presently I don't have time for this, but I'll verify this on the weekend (will come back to you). It might still be that your answer is valid after all due to this detail :-)

Comment: The documentation *isn't* authoritative, the code *is*. Interestingly the kernel does a read fault on the page during the acquisition of the lock, so VirtualLock will definitely page stuff back in from the pagefile, and the paging APC won't allow the page to go out to the pagefile (although the hibernation process will overrule it - so still no guarantee there). It won't convert CopyOnWrite pages to writeable pages, so MSDN is wrong when it says it protects against page-faults in that area. It merely protects against read-faults in that area.

Answer (score 3):

> *`VirtualLock` remains a no-op (fault-wise)*

I tried to reproduce this, but it worked as one might expect. Running the example code shown at the bottom of this post:

- start application (523 page faults)
- adjust the working set size (21 page faults)
- `VirtualAlloc` with `MEM_COMMIT` 2500 MB of RAM (2 page faults)
- `VirtualLock` all of that (**about 641,250 page faults**)
- perform writes to all of this RAM in an infinite loop (zero page faults)

This all works pretty much as expected. 2500 MB of RAM is 640,000 pages. The numbers add up. Also, as far as the OS-wide RAM counters go, commit charge goes up at `VirtualAlloc`, while physical memory usage goes up at `VirtualLock`.

So `VirtualLock` is most definitely *not* a no-op on my Win7 x64 machine. If I don't do it, the page faults, as expected, shift to where I start writing to the RAM. They still total just over 640,000. Plus, the first time the memory is written to takes longer.

---

> *Rather, as it looks, each single accessed page is created upon faulting, even if it had been locked previously.*

This is not *wrong*. There is no guarantee that accessing a locked-then-unlocked page won't fault. You lock it, it gets mapped to physical RAM. You unlock it, and it's free to be unmapped instantly, making a fault possible. You might hope it will stay mapped, but no guarantees...

For what it's worth, on my system with a few gigabytes of physical RAM free, it works the way you were hoping for: even if I follow my `VirtualLock` with an immediate `VirtualUnlock` and set the minimum working set size back to something small, no further page faults occur.

Here's what I did. I ran the test program (below) with and without the code that immediately unlocks the memory and restores a sensible minimum working set size, and then forced physical RAM to run out in each scenario. Before forcing low RAM, neither program gets any page faults. After forcing low RAM, the program that keeps the memory locked retains its huge working set and has no further page faults. The program that unlocked the memory, however, starts getting page faults.

This is easiest to observe if you suspend the process first, since otherwise the constant memory writes keep it all in the working set even if the memory isn't locked (obviously a desirable thing). But suspend the process, force low RAM, and watch the working set shrink only for the program that has unlocked the RAM. Resume the process, and witness an avalanche of page faults.

In other words, at least in Win7 x64 everything works exactly as you expected it to, using the code supplied below.

---

> *There are two problems with tampering the WS size, however. First, you're generally not meant to have a gigabyte of minimum working set in a process*

Well... if you want to `VirtualLock`, you are already tampering with it. The only thing that `SetProcessWorkingSetSize` does is *allow* you to tamper with it. It doesn't degrade performance by itself; it's `VirtualLock` that does - but only if the system actually runs low on physical RAM.

---

Here's the complete program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    SIZE_T chunkSize = 2500LL * 1024LL * 1024LL; // 2,626,568,192 = 640,000 pages
    int sleep = 5000;

    Sleep(sleep);

    cout << "Setting working set size... ";
    if (!SetProcessWorkingSetSize(GetCurrentProcess(), chunkSize + 5001001L, chunkSize * 2))
        return -1;
    cout << "done" << endl;

    Sleep(sleep);

    cout << "VirtualAlloc... ";
    UINT8* data = (UINT8*) VirtualAlloc(NULL, chunkSize, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
    if (data == NULL)
        return -2;
    cout << "done" << endl;

    Sleep(sleep);

    cout << "VirtualLock... ";
    if (VirtualLock(data, chunkSize) == 0)
        return -3;
    //if (VirtualUnlock(data, chunkSize) == 0) // enable or disable to experiment with unlocks
    //    return -3;
    //if (!SetProcessWorkingSetSize(GetCurrentProcess(), 5001001L, chunkSize * 2))
    //    return -1;
    cout << "done" << endl;

    Sleep(sleep);

    cout << "Writes to the memory... ";
    while (true)
    {
        int* end = (int*) (data + chunkSize);
        for (int* d = (int*) data; d < end; d++)
            *d = (int) d;
        cout << "done ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Note that this code puts the thread to sleep after `VirtualLock`. According to a [2007 post by Raymond Chen](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/11/06/5924058.aspx), the OS is free to page it all out of physical RAM at this point and until the thread wakes up again. Note also that [MSDN claims otherwise](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa366895%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), saying that this memory will not be paged out, regardless of whether all threads are sleeping or not. On my system, they certainly remain in the physical RAM while the only thread is sleeping. I suspect Raymond's advice applied in 2007, but is no longer true in Win7.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, so I'll have to add this as an answer.

> Note that this code puts the thread to sleep after VirtualLock. According to a 2007 post by Raymond Chen, the OS is free to page it all out of physical RAM at this point and until the thread wakes up again [...] I suspect Raymond's advice applied in 2007, but is no longer true in Win7.

What romkyns said has [been confirmed by Raymond Chen](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2014/02/07/10497475.aspx) in 2014. That is, when you lock memory with Virtual­Lock, it will remain locked even if all your threads are blocked. He also says the fact that pages remain locked, may be just an implementation detail and not contractual.

This is probably not the case, because according to msdn, it is contractual

> Pages that a process has locked remain in physical memory until the process unlocks them or terminates. These pages are guaranteed not to be written to the pagefile while they are locked.