# What is the difference between committing and locking virtual memory?

Tags: c, memory-management

There are some C functions.

For example; `VirtualAlloc()` reserves and commits and `VirtualLock()` lockes a region of the virtual memory space.

What's the difference between them?

Answer (score 2):

> VirtualLock locks the specified region of the process's virtual
>   address space into physical memory, ensuring that **subsequent access to
>   the region will not incur a page fault**.

`VirtualAlloc` requests memory from the kernel - i.e. after the allocation you get a new chunk of memory to play with. The kernel often needs to swap out memory to make room for other stuff. `VirtualLock` asks the kernel **not to swap out a region of memory**.

Comment: +1, though note that the documentation to `VirtualLock` that you (correctly) quoted is lying. The wording "will not incur a page fault" suggests that pages that do not exist yet are created, but this is not the case. At best, `VirtualLock` will prevent existing pages to be swapped out (if it doesn't just fail silently, which it usually does because few people are aware of the ridiculously low working set defaults and few people actually check the return code).

Comment: @Damon Nice, good to know. I actually have little experience with win32 programming.

Comment: You can read a bit about my observations [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7874281/572743) if you're interested. In one word, it's disappointing, because what you measure is not what you think should happen, nor what you're told.