# How to ensure that memory mapped files are always in RAM

Tags: ipc, memory-mapped-files, win64

Is it possible to create a memory mapped file for interprocess communication with a guarantee that the content is always being kept in RAM and not flushed to page file?

I am currently working on a bespoke OLAP app. The core idea is to have one process like a memory bank which contains all the data, and multiple worker processes which actually do the calculation. While usually everything works very smoothely, from time to time there is a performance hiccup when a worker tries to create a view on a part of a file which has not been used for a while - hence my question.

Amount of RAM is not a problem (Windows/64 bit) - we just do not know whether it is possible to stop the system from using a page file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for the [`VirtualLock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366895) function.

> Locks the specified region of the process's virtual address space into
>   physical memory, ensuring that subsequent access to the region will
>   not incur a page fault.

[*Caveat lector*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7874281/unexpected-page-handling-also-virtuallock-no-op).

Comment: Thank you - that is exactly what I need. And thank you for the warning - I will proceed to investigate what potential side effects this solution could bring to the project.