# Is it true that when memory is allocated into a process in Windows, it always triggers a page fault?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

I'm trying to wrap my head around the internals of Windows memory management at the OS level.

Is it true that when memory is allocated, it always triggers a page fault behind the scenes? Does this imply that the only way to stop soft page faults is to stop allocating new memory within the process?

**Definitions**

I define "memory allocation" as any form of malloc, i.e. new, LocalAlloc, VirtualAlloc, HeapAlloc, etc.

I define a "page fault" as the process of mapping memory from the OS pool into the process Working Set, an operation which takes a constant 250us on a high end Xeon.

Comment: "Is it true that when memory is allocated, it always triggers a page fault? In other words, the only way to stop page faults is to stop allocating new memory" Logically, if the first sentence is true, this doesn't mean, that the second is true as well.

Comment: Your "250us on a high end Xeon" is way off. I'm not sure where you got that from. 6us is typical.

Comment: @Alex Farber. You are correct. The first sentence does not imply the second. However, is the second sentence correct? I have clarified the second statement.

Comment: LocalAlloc and HeapAllioc are a higher level than VirtualAlloc. If LocalAlloc and HeapAlloc can find recently freed (and not decommitted) memory to reuse, they can do that without incurring a page fault. The page fault is incurred on first access to committed memory.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: _"Your '250us on a high end Xeon' is way off [...] 6us is typical."_ -- Hehehe, yes... one should seriously hope so! On my no-high-end Core2 which runs in power-save mode, some memory hungry processes have upwards of 25,000 faults per second. At 250µs per fault, the computer would stop doing anything _except handling faults_ at 4,000 faults per second.

Comment: @Damon You are correct, page faults do not take that long (although they do last that long on our system - there must be something else going).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to be very clear about the different things that are going on here. There are two independent parts to the process, committing the memory and paging the memory into the process. Neither of these are related to calling `malloc`, `HeapAlloc` or `LocalAlloc`.

I've tried to break the process down for you below, but the summary is that if you use `HeapAlloc` or another equivalent function then you'll trigger very few page-faults (at least once your application has initialized and the heap has grown to a stable size) and so shouldn't worry about it too much.

**Allocating memory**

When you call `malloc`, `HeapAlloc` or `LocalAlloc` the memory allocator will try to find a piece of memory in the heap that's available and large enough. In the majority of cases it will succeed and return the memory to you.

If it can not find sufficient memory it will allocate more by calling `VirtualAlloc` (on Linux this would be `sbrk` or `mmap`). This *commits* the memory. It will return a small fragment of the new memory to you.

**Memory commitment**

When you, or the allocator, call `VirtualAlloc` this will mark a new region of your virtual memory as accessible. This does not trigger a page-fault, nor does it actually assign physical memory to those pages. From the MSDN docs for VirtualAlloc:

> Allocates memory charges (from the overall size of memory and the paging files on disk) 
>   for the specified reserved memory pages. The function also guarantees that when the caller 
>   later initially accesses the memory, the contents will be zero. Actual physical pages are 
>   not allocated unless/until the virtual addresses are actually accessed.

**Paging memory in**

When you access a page of memory that `VirtualAlloc` has returned to you for the first time this triggers a soft page-fault. The operating system will find a single page of free physical memory, zero it out and assign it to the virtual page you accessed. This is transparent to you and takes very little time (a single-digit number of microseconds). It's plausible that the operating system may swap this memory out to disk if you stop using it, if it does then a subsequent access will trigger a hard page-fault.

Comment: Surely a better answer than my half-guesses!

Comment: @jleahy Truly superb answer, I understand whats going on now. More importantly, I think this opens up a technique to eliminate all of the page faults in our .NET app, by increasing the size of the Working Set to 8GB with a C++ .dll.

Comment: Quote from MSDN on VirtuaLock, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366895(v=vs.85).aspx. "Each version of Windows has a limit on the maximum number of pages a process can lock. This limit is intentionally small to avoid severe performance degradation. Applications that need to lock larger numbers of pages must first call the SetProcessWorkingSetSize function to increase their minimum and maximum working set sizes ... Pages that a process has locked remain in physical memory ... These pages are guaranteed not to be written to the pagefile while they are locked."

Comment: @Gravitas I wasn't aware of that function, that's quite nice. If you want to completely eliminate page-faults you should also pre-fault the stack. Allocate a large buffer in a function and memset it to some dummy value, that way you can avoid a page-fault when you make an unusually deep call for the first time.

Comment: @jleahy In addition, I believe calls to VirtualLock to lock more than 64MB of memory will fail, possibly silently, unless SetProcessWorkingSetSizeEx at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686237(v=vs.85).aspx is first called to increase the maximum size of the WorkingSet above the (tiny) default set by Windows. SetProcessWorkingSetSizeEx sets the minimum size of the WorkingSet that Windows will leave in memory, and not page out to the page file (this will help to eliminate hard page faults).

Answer (score 1):

Well, yes, a page fault will bring the CPU back into kernel mode, and the kernel gets a chance to learn that the userspace process wanted a certain memory page. The kernel can then consult its internal memory management bookkeeping data, make a suitably large area of physical memory available, and adjust the processor's page table so that the requested virtual address is mapped. Once that's done, execution passes back to the userspace process, which resumes with a successful allocation.

This is not to be confused with an *unexpected* page fault, by which the userspace process refers to an address that is neither mapped in the page tables *nor* known to the kernel's memory manager to belong to the process. In that case, the kernel will kill the rogue process.

Comment: But can't the allocation be made just within existing (in page table) memory pages?

Comment: @raina77ow: The userspace allocation function won't even go to the kernel if there's already enough userspace memory available. The situation in question only arises if you're genuinely out of userspace memory and need to get more from the kernel.

Comment: @raina77ow Is there a way to pre-allocate memory from the kernel into the userspace, so any line of code that does malloc in user space does not generate a page fault?

Comment: @Gravitas: Not portably to my knowledge, but I imagine if you `malloc` and immediately `free` a huge amount of memory, you retain the pages. No promise, though! (tcmalloc in Linux never returns memory, so that does indeed have that behaviour.)

Comment: @Gravitas Well, from what I've read about [allocation strategies](http://www.flounder.com/memory_allocation.htm), they actually differ on amount of page faults; hence my question to Kerrek SB. )

Comment: Allocating and freeing is not enough, but allocating, _touching_, and freeing should be, provided that you've adjusted your minimum working set size (the default is ridiculously low, so page faults happen _all the time_). Allocating and freeing (even locking) is a no-op unless actually touching every page.

Comment: @Damon Really interesting. Every time I've allocated, touched, called SetProcessWorkingSetSizeEx then freed, the Working Set still shrinks down. I'm wondering if you know of any sample code that shows how to increase the WorkingSet to avoid page faults in the future?

Comment: @Gravitas: The minimum working set size is the important number (it's what Windows will keep present _as long as a thread of your process executes_ -- not necessarily any longer, unluckily -- if possible). The findings about touching and working sets come from Raymond Chen's comments to my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7874281/unexpected-page-handling-also-virtuallock-no-op) and the article linked to by SecurityMatt. In summary, you will _still_ see faults, nothing you can do about -- you can just avoid having them all the time, every time.

Comment: @Damon Excellent. If you are correct, then you have invalidated my original statement, which would be very cool from my point of view (I could reduce the number of page faults in my app by increasing the Working Set).