# Does VirtualLock really do what it say?

Tags: c++, c, windows

For security purpose, I'm currently studying how to avoid some chunk of data from being swapped during the execution of a program.

As far as I search, I found mlock on Linux, which seems to be exactly the tool I need, and VirtualLock on Windows.

For the latter, I found different opinions. The [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366895(v=vs.85).aspx) says that

> Pages that a process has locked remain in physical memory until the process unlocks them or terminates.

However, people seems to disagree and claim that [VirtualLock only lock the memory in the working set of the process](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20071106-00/?p=24573), so the memory will not be swapped as long as at least one thread of the program is running. This means that if for whatever reason every threads are blocked, data might be swapped out.

Could anyone clarify this point for me ? 
And if the documentation is indeed wrong, is this just a theorical risk, or should I seriously consider it ? What solution could I use to *really* lock memory in RAM ?

If it can help, my goal is to identify good practice and bad practice for erasing memory in crypto application

**Edit** : [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140207-00/?p=1833) Answer the question, it is definitely lock in RAM. However it raise an other one : how to get rid of the cache issue ? I may end up with several copies of my data...

Comment: I think this explains it: Each version of Windows has a limit on the maximum number of pages a process can lock. This limit is intentionally small to avoid severe performance degradation. Applications that need to lock larger numbers of pages must first call the SetProcessWorkingSetSize function to increase their minimum and maximum working set sizes. The maximum number of pages that a process can lock is equal to the number of pages in its minimum working set minus a small overhead.

Comment: As well as swapping, you also need to worry about hibernation or hybrid sleep saving RAM contents to disk.

Comment: Why do you bother? In user mode *anything* can delay your process, not just memory pages being swapped out. If you need realtime performance you need to go kernel mode.

Comment: @drescherjm It doesn't really answer my question, I was aware of this limitation, but my reading (I add a link in my post), but that's not my point. I'm worring about what VirtualLock do when it "lock" memory.

Comment: @IanAbbott I was aware of the hibernation issue, and I will definitely check hybrid sleep, thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @Faulst it looks like [it does keep it in ram, but you may still have cache misses](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140207-00/?p=1833)

Comment: @rustyx I know that's tricky to manage this kind of things from user space, but I have to study what I can do in this position

Comment: @Mgetz It's actually the correction of the article which made me wonder, I didn't know it existed ! Ok, that answer my question pretty well, but that raise an other problem...

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7874281/332733)

Comment: @Faulst I can think of a few ways around it... but all of them are really really bad ideas overall. Realistically I'd highly suggest against this unless you have benchmarks that suggest you need to do this. If you need security I'd suggest [`CryptProtectMemory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380262(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: @Mgetz Thanks I will check it out. My final purpose being to identify good practice and bad practice for erasing memory in crypto application, it might be useful.  It remind me the .NET SecureString process

Comment: Also might want to have a look at Intel SGX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need security you realistically have two options:

1. Move to kernel mode
2. Encrypt the data in memory using [`CryptProtectMemory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380262(v=vs.85).aspx)

The problem is that even if you lock the ram in place other processes can read it if they have the right access rights. There are ways using process isolation to potentially prevent this but they require access to an SDK that MS limits to DRM developers.

Remember when you're done with the memory you'll need to clear it with `SecureZeroMemory` which the compiler will not optimize away.

Comment: You can set the discretionary security of your process to prevent non-admin users from getting VM read access. I wouldn't worry about admins and users with debug privilege. They have a legitimate right, other than "intellectual property" issues.

Comment: @eryksun do you have a link to an example of how to do that? I'll incorporate it into the answer

Answer (score 0):

What about using enclaves? https://openenclave.io/sdk/
Tldr: It uses a new CPU feature that allows to isolate a certain range of memory even from kernel mode code:

"An enclave application partitions itself into two components (1) An untrusted component (called the host) and (2) A trusted component (called the enclave). An enclave is a secure container whose memory is protected from entities outside the enclave. These protections allow enclaves to perform secure computations with assurances that secrets will not be compromised."