# How to find how much memory has been locked by a process under Windows?

Tags: windows, winapi

Under Linux, I can get this info by looking at `VmLck` in `/proc/$PID/status`.

But on Windows, I couldn't find anything about how to find the current size of memory that's been locked so far of a certain process, in a programatical way (using WinAPI).

Comment: Does Windows even have equivalent functionality? Do any of the memory protection constants here (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/Memory/memory-protection-constants) look like they prevent memory from being paged to swap file?

Comment: It does, VirtualLock() function.  Iterate the working set to find the Locked flag back: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/psapi/ns-psapi-_psapi_working_set_ex_information

Comment: Basically, get all of the working set pages via `QueryWorkingSet` and check them individually via `QueryWorkingSetEx`.

Comment: Physical mappings (i.e. `MEM_PHYSICAL`) should also show up as locked pages, e.g. via AWE `AllocateUserPhysicalPages` and `MapUserPhysicalPages`.

Comment: @eryksun Afaik, AWE are not part of the working set (See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/memory/working-set) So the idea is to iterate on all the pages in the working set, get the Locked flag and finally have the count of locked pages and do the math right?

Comment: Why do you need that information? Generally, there are lots of differences between nix and Windows and many programmers coming from linux try to achieve things in Windows that have no meaning, unless you need something specific which can be done using another (and probably safer) API call. Also check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49676457/does-virtuallock-really-do-what-it-say

Comment: @MiD, physically mapped pages won't be in the working set, but `QueryWorkingSetEx` will show them as locked. You'll have to walk pages that are outside the working set. `VirtualQueryEx` doesn't help since a physical mapping is reported simply as committed, private memory.